# If else statement not working in javascript onclick() when called from android webview?

Tags: javascript, android, if-statement, onclick, buttonclick

During `onClick()` function which has a if else statement inside it is not working properly from android webview. I have added the code below.
Kindly provide your suggestion were I am missing it.
Thanks a lot.

```
function exampleCall(message) { 

   if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)) {
      androidexampleCall(message);
   }

   if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i)){
       iOSexampleCall(message);
   }                            
}
```

JS call:

`<div onclick="javascript:exampleCall('GameOn');">.... </div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the call that is not working is `androidexampleCall(message)`.

Define a interface and add it to the webview on your activity, like:

```
 Webview wv;
 //... 
 wv.addJavascriptInterface(new myJavaScriptInterface(), "CallToAnAndroidFunction");
 //...
 public class myJavaScriptInterface {
     @JavascriptInterface
     public void androidexampleCall(String message);{
        //code
     }
 }
```

On your Js code you should do the call as follows:

```
 function exampleCall(message) { 

   if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)) {
     window.CallToAnAndroidFunction.androidexampleCall(message);
   }

   if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i)){
     iOSexampleCall(message);
   }                            
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,We need to add "window.CallToAnAndroidFunction.androidexampleCall(message);" this in javascript or in android code..

Comment: I followed the code but I am able to get the output only when I place it outside the if-else statement.Its not working when I place inside if-else statement.How can I rectify this.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you didn't enabled Javascript for your Webview:

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

**EDIT:**

Tested your code with this Webview:

```
webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webview.loadUrl("http://jonathanalbrieux.com/others/testagent.html");

Button buttonReload = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
buttonReload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        webview.loadUrl("http://jonathanalbrieux.com/others/testagent.html");

    }
});
```

And this page:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="clickable" onclick="test('a')">clickaqd</div>
    <script>

        function test(string){
            if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)) {
                var divClickable = document.getElementById("clickable");
                divClickable.innerHTML = string;
            }

        }
    </script>
</body>
```

And everything works correctly, maybe you have some problem in `androidexampleCall` function.

Comment: Jonathan my javascript code works but the above scenario when I place it android code in if-else statement it doesnt' work..